# Proxy for ethereum wallet

Tags: proxy, ethereum

Env: Ubuntu 16.04
I am working behind a proxy. Wanted to know how to pass the proxy info to the Ethereum wallet.
My http_proxy and https_proxy are set still it is not taking
when i start the ethereum wallet i see that following error

```
[2017-07-25 11:12:15.030] [ERROR] updateChecker - Error checking for update { RequestError: Connection timed out on request to api.github.com
    at ClientRequest.req.once.err (/home/nokia/go-ether/mist/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/node_modules/got/index.js:73:21)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Timeout.timeoutHandler (/home/nokia/go-ether/mist/linux-unpacked/resources/app.asar/node_modules/timed-out/index.js:16:8)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  message: 'Connection timed out on request to api.github.com'
```

which i think is coming because it is not able to access proxy settings.

So how can i pass the proxy info to the wallet
Thanks

Comment: Hello. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No not resolved. but my wallet is launching even if this fails.